# Quit Cell Margin CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I want to fit text inside a table row

I have this:

[image: Current]

I want the last `<tr>` like:

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCnCr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post any code (= not good...), but in general, if you mean that there should not be any space above and below the text in the cells of the last row, this should work:

```
tr:last-child > td { 
  padding-top:0; 
  padding-bottom: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not shure how your code looks but you propably should play with line-height of your **td** text, for example:

```
table, td { 
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid black;

  line-height:12px;
}
```

Or remove padding from **td** if there is any:

```
td {
   padding: 0;
}
```